# infragistics data-picker, using property "dateInputFormat" causes month selection not to be accepted

Tags: javascript, jquery, infragistics, durandal

I work in durandal project.
I wrote this code:

```
$('#leftDatePicker').igDatePicker({

    dateInputFormat: "d-m-yy",
    dateDisplayFormat: "d-m-yy",
    datepickerOptions: {
        minDate: d,  
        yearRange: "2011:2014",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    }
});
```

Since I add the property `dateInputFormat: "d-m-yy",`, the datepicker show as I selected month number 0! and if I change it manually it leaves the new value that I put, regardless the selections from the calendar. for example:

I'm choosing year number 2013, month Jun, and date 4; it shows: 4-0-2013. If I write by myself 4-6-2013 and after this I select, for example, year 2014, month Aug and date 2, it shows: 2-6-2014, even though Aug is month number 8! It doesn't change the month to match my selection.

Comment: Did you even look up the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what it looks like in these [docs](http://help.infragistics.com/jQuery/2012.1/ui.igdatepicker#options), you need to use a capital `M`

```
"M": month field as digit without leading zero
"MM": month field as digit with leading zero
"MMM": month field as short month name
"MMMM": month field as long month name
```

Lowercase is minutes:

```
"m": minutes field without leading zero
"mm": minutes field with leading zero
```

Comment: thank you very much, it help me. now my employer is pleased. continue being so caring. good luck.